# Inputs on datatables

Tags: jquery

I'm using DataTables and so far it has been great. The problem is that I can't say that I know enough javascript to be able to edit some of it functionalities:

Right now I'm using this thing: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

What I want is to get rid of that search box and put in the same place 2 `<select>` inputs that work the same way as in the link

Thank you.

Comment: To remove the search box, you can initiate the datatable with searchable false like `$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
    { "searchable": false },
  ] } );
} );`

Comment: @gaganshera what about the 2 selects instead of the search?

Comment: Just use jquery to add the 2 select boxes in the datatable like you'd normally do. Look up dynamically adding elements using jquery. If you still have doubts, I'll post an answer in a while.

Comment: @gaganshera my jquery knowledge is pretty poor. Waiting on you. Thank you!